# Не получается запустить программу на QT, что делать?

Tags: qt, qt5

> ```
> 21:38:14: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled...
> 21:38:14: Запускается: «D:\Qt\5.12.0\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe» C:\Users\Дмитрий\Documents\untitled\untitled.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
> Cannot find file: C:\Users\Дмитрий\Documents\untitled\untitled.pro.
> 21:38:14: Процесс «D:\Qt\5.12.0\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe» завершился с кодом 2.
> Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.12.0 MinGW 64 bit)
> Во время выполнения этапа «qmake»
> 21:38:14: Прошло времени: 00:00.
> ```

Comment: кириллицу в пути к проекту уберите

Comment: и qt creator лучше переключите в английский, иначе его бывает трудно понять

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, из-за пути содержащий кириллицу

Comment: У меня также складывается впечатление, что тревогающие ответ как "не является ответом" ориентируются в первую очередь на длину ответа, в то время как где-то на мете было обсуждение, насколько подробно нужно расписывать ответ. Вот [одно из них](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7839/213987) и [ещё одно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4886/213987).